# Anguar node_modules: how to cleanup?

Tags: npm

Having an Angular project I have a node_modules directory in my project dir.
That is pretty full with all the files of the modules I use.

I like to periodically save the project folder for backup. Doing this takes a bit of time because of node_modules.

Is it a bad idea to remove nodes_modules before backup and then after doing more coding rebuild it with

```
npm install
```

?
Or maybe theres a better way to have smaller backups?

**EDIT**

I do git and also this directory-backup. My question is regarding the directory-backup only.

Comment: where do you backup your code? if you do it in github add node_modules to gitignore file and if you use svn add it to svnignore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `package.json` file act  as a blue print for your required node modules with versions of every node module being used in the project, hence keeping a back up of node_module doesn't make sense, as you can get it back with a `npm install` on your project anytime

If you are using Git, you can ignore node_modules by adding the following in .gitignore file

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```

Answer (score 1):

`node_modules` and `package-lock.json` should not be backed up it should be installed when used as all data is present in `package.json`

Please use a version control system shuch as `git` instead of manual backups

Check this link for better understanding

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: The lock file absolutely *should* be in version control, so you can reproduce builds across machines.

Comment: It gets recreated when you run npm install

Comment: Yes, it does, but *not necessarily with the same content*. If you're not committing it, you might as well disable its creation.